# IApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for UseWebApi

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-1.0

The VS 2015 Update 3 is out and I have started playing with it. But I hit a problem soon after. The IApplicationBuilder interface does not appear to have a definition for the UseWebApi extension method, but IAppBuilder does. In effect, I want to register my Web Api with the OWIN pipeline. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

NuGet command:

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost`

[Source](https://musthaan.com/2016/01/29/iappbuilder-does-not-contain-definition-for-usewebapi/)

Comment: Yip this was what I needed in my framework project.

Comment: underrated answer. but I wonder why they don't include this in the owin core package.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the *IApplicationBuilder* interface to have a definition for the UseWebApi extension method. In *IAppBuilder*, it was used to register a Web Api with OWIN. But for *IApplicationBuilder*, because ASP.NET Core uses a unified model for both Web Api and MVC services, simply use the **IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc** method. It works!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `UseWebApi` in Asp.NET Core so I am not sure what the "relevant package" is. [Here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html) is a tutorial showing how to build Web API with Asp.NET Core.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I have updated my question. I'm an ASP.NET Core newbie.