# How to configure OWIN Web API 1 via IAppBuilder

Tags: owin, katana

**TL;DR: How do I configure OWIN Web API 1 via a StartUp class or alternatively use the HttpSelfHostServer with the static files extension?**

I have a working self-hosted OWIN Web API 2 project, which I'd like to downgrade to .Net 4.0 - I'd prefer not to install the .Net 4.5+ framework replacement, because of [unknown side-effects on a production machine](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/mar/13/net-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-net-40).

I can't use [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163548/iapplicationbuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-usewebapi) because it's not available for .Net 4.0 and therefore I can't call the `IAppBuilder.useWebApi()` extension method for registering my configuration.

I'm bootstraping the server now like this: `WebApp.Start(Of StartUp)(url:="...")`
and the StartUp class looks like this, **but I can't set the config**:

```
Public Class StartUp
Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
    ' the host should be obsolete, as it's already configured in the app context
    Dim config As New HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:9000")

    ' config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )

    ' configure formatters, converters, filters ...

    ' app.UseWebApi(config)

    Dim physicalFileSystem As New PhysicalFileSystem("...\static")
    app.UseDefaultFiles(New DefaultFilesOptions With {.FileSystem = physicalFileSystem})
    app.UseStaticFiles(New StaticFileOptions With {.FileSystem = physicalFileSystem, .ServeUnknownFileTypes = True})
End Sub
End Class
```

If I'd use the documented [Web API 1 approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api) of bootstrapping the server (see below), I don't know how to configure the static files extension:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}", 
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config)) {
    server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Although I've checked the [AspNetWebStack sources](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http.Owin/WebApiAppBuilderExtensions.cs), I think the message handling has changed between V2.1.0 and V5.0.0+ and therefore I can't apply that approach.

I'm using the following nuget packages - which I might reduce after its working:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.6" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

*Btw. although I've used VB.Net in the example, feel free to use your preferred language in your answer.*

Comment: ... in the meantime, I was informed that actually .net 4.6 is installed on the machine, so this renders my approach obsolete ... :S